# Can computed be an observable too in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I have first name and last name as an observable, username is computed. Is it possible to make username observable too ?

Comment: A computed is already an observable. What exactly do you want to be able to do?

Comment: Ok I am computing username based on first and last name. That's data bound to a textbox. 
If I edit the textbox it doesn't update the computed.

Comment: Knockout would need to know how to take the value and divide it among the variables it's composed from. For this you'll need to have a `write` function that described how to transform from one input value to many observable values. See the update to my answer with a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computed in Knockout is already a type of observable. If what you want to be able to do is set the value of a computed then you can do so using the `read` and `write` properties.

Here's a very crude example of setting the first and last name:

```
var fn = ko.observable("Jimbo");
var ln = ko.observable("Jangles");

var vm = {
    myComputed : ko.computed({
        read: function () { return fn() + " " + ln(); },
        write: function (value) {
            var pieces = value.split(" ");
            fn(pieces[0]);
            ln(pieces[pieces.length -1]);
        }
    })
};
```

Here's a working example:http://jsfiddle.net/xxkLs0p8/

Comment: Thanks for quick working example. Really appreciated. The thing is that changing the username should not update the other observable. In short - Changing the computed should not affect the values of other observable. e.g Two textbox data bound to same computed. Update the value in one textbox should update the value in the other.

Comment: In that case you can just update a separate variable and check if it's undefined in the read. Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/xxkLs0p8/2/

Comment: `fullName` just needed to be made into an observable: http://jsfiddle.net/xxkLs0p8/5/